# Make check boxes disappear if the value of another field is equal to a specific string

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to make the checkboxes in the record disappear if the value of the field is equal to "Basic Actions".  I would also like to make the font bold turning it into a header.

I have tried the .Visible and .Fontbold properties using an If-Then statement.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

    If Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.StandardAction = "Basic Actions" Then
        Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.StandardAction.FontBold = True
        Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.StartTimeChallengeYes.Visible = False
        Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.StartTimeChallengeNo.Visible = False
        Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.ActivityChallengeYes.Visible = False
        Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.ActivityChallengeNo.Visible = False
    Else
        Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.StandardAction.FontBold = False
        Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.StartTimeChallengeYes.Visible = True
        Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.StartTimeChallengeNo.Visible = True
        Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.ActivityChallengeYes.Visible = True
        Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.ActivityChallengeNo.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

I'm not getting any error messages, the form loads, but without the needed changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Form_Current` event.
On the control say:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If (Me.Textbox1.Value = Me.Textbox2.Value) Then
Me.Textbox2.Visible = False
Me.Textbox3.FontBold = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This didn't work either.  I have tried so many different ways to do this, I think it has something to do with the checkboxes themselves, but not sure.  I used this code                                                            Private Sub Form_Current()

If Me.StartTimeChallengeYes.Value = True Then
Me.StartTimeChallengeYes.Visible = False
Else
Me.StartTimeChallengeYes.Visible = True
End If

End Sub